# Raspbian 9.9 Stretch - Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch, connection, dhcp, pi-hole

I have pihole(with DHCP server enabled, router DHCP server disabled) and SMB running on my raspberry pi, and my network interfaces are acting rather strange. From my raspberry pi, I can ping my router and PC with no problems

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.144 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.125 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.136 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3128ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.125/0.135/0.144/0.015 ms
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 192.168.1.107
PING 192.168.1.107 (192.168.1.107) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.107: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.144 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.107: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.144 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.107: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.139 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.107: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.107 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3112ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.138/0.141/0.144/0.008 ms
```

but I cannot ping my raspberry pi from my PC, nor can I ping any websites from my raspberry pi.

```
C:\Windows\System32\>arp -a
Interface: 192.168.1.107 --- 0xb
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.1.1           b0-e1-7e-e2-54-9a     dynamic   
192.168.1.128         b8-27-eb-9e-9c-0d     dynamic   
192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static   

C:\Windows\system32> ping 192.168.1.128    
Pinging 192.168.1.128 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.128:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

here's the output of `ifconfig -a` and `iwconfig` on my raspberry pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fecb:c958  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:cb:c9:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11614  bytes 1283123 (1.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1381  bytes 177648 (173.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3232686  bytes 216669866 (206.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3232686  bytes 216669866 (206.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9e:9c0d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:9e:9c:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6672  bytes 916399 (894.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1805  bytes 255613 (249.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Winnie The Pooh"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: B0:E1:7E:E2:54:9B   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:8  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

however, entering `ifup` or `ifdown` for eth0 and wlan0, I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
ifdown: unknown interface eth0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0
ifdown: unknown interface wlan0
```

This is what my dhcpcd.conf looks like:

```
interface enxb827ebcbc958
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.128
static ip_address=192.168.1.128
static domain_search=

interface wlan0
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.128
static ip_address=192.168.1.128
static domain_search=

interface lo
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.128
static ip_address=192.168.1.128
static domain_search=

interface eth0
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.128
static ip_address=192.168.1.128
static domain_search=
```

and this is the output I get when I check on dhcpcd:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-11-04 01:16:51 HKT; 7h ago
  Process: 404 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 429 (dhcpcd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─429 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b
           └─610 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext

Nov 04 01:35:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: carrier lost
Nov 04 01:35:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9e:9c0d
Nov 04 01:35:10 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Nov 04 01:35:10 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: IAID eb:9e:9c:0d
Nov 04 01:35:10 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: adding address fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9e:9c0d
Nov 04 01:35:10 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: using static address 192.168.1.128/24
Nov 04 01:35:10 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: preferring 192.168.1.128 on lo
Nov 04 01:35:10 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Nov 04 01:35:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
Nov 04 01:35:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

and I get this when I enter `sudo route -n`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     201    0        0 lo
```

Updated with files/outputs requested by others:
`ip -a` output from raspberry pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.128/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:cb:c9:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fecb:c958/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:9e:9c:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9e:9c0d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`02-pihole-dhcp.conf` from pi:

```
###############################################################################
#  DHCP SERVER CONFIG FILE AUTOMATICALLY POPULATED BY PI-HOLE WEB INTERFACE.  #
#            ANY CHANGES MADE TO THIS FILE WILL BE LOST ON CHANGE             #
###############################################################################
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.255,infinite
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.1.1
dhcp-leasefile=/etc/pihole/dhcp.leases
#quiet-dhcp

domain=local
dhcp-rapid-commit
#quiet-dhcp6
#enable-ra
dhcp-option=option6:dns-server,[::]
dhcp-range=::100,::1ff,constructor:eth0,ra-names,slaac,infinite
ra-param=*,0,0
```

`route print` from my PC:

```
C:\Windows\system32> route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 21...00 1a 7d da 71 13 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
 11...9c 5c 8e 86 d6 50 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.107    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
    192.168.1.107  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.107    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 11    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    266 fe80::1c9e:355a:914f:4821/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: I don't know about Pihole but your `dhcpcd.conf` is a mess! For a start you are trying to assign the same IP Address to 4 interfaces (including lo which is nonsense)! This probably isn't actually doing anything as `ifconfig -a` shows no IP Address has been assigned. (You should use `ip a` instead). Without knowing what you have done it is not possible to be more precise.

Comment: so, you disabled dhcp on the router and configured DHCP server on the Pi? Can you show the DHCP server configuration of the pi (not dhcpcd as that is the client)

Comment: also, show the result of `route print` on your PC

Comment: The fact that your `route` on raspberry pi uses `lo` interface looks dodgy

Comment: Please edit your question and put requested output into it instead of using external links.

Comment: Removed comments linking to external sites, updated main post.